# Importing "Ø" (special character) in Magento

Tags: import, csv

I had a lot of problems with the Export and Import of Products through a CSV file.

My main issue is that in Germany MS Excel generally uses ";" as a delimiter instead of ",".
I tried a few work arounds, but in the end now I changed Mangeto's delimiter settings so I export and import with ";" as delimiter, now the CSV file is beeing correctly displayed in MS Excel.
 1. Question: What do you think about that?

A lot of products use the "Ø"-sign for the diameter of our round carpets in the shop, yes we sell carpets by the way.
I got the error "sku is not defined" for around 200/500 rows, I found out that this issue is due to the "Ø", because when I replaced this sign, everything worked fine. The strange thing about that is, that I am pretty sure, well 99,9% sure, the import of products with "Ø" in the name worked before. It may be that I had different System settings for Windows and maybe different coding settings in MS Excel, everything got a little bit confused and changed, maybe that is the reason.
 1. Question: Do you know if it is possibe for me to import with special characters like "Ø" and if yes, how? Btw I use "alt" + "0216" (German keyboard) for this sign.

Kai

Answer (score 1):

Look into [UTF-8 Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

You should be able upon saving the MS Excel doc to use `,` instead of `;` without any repercussions. I believe you can also provide an escape sequence or text delimiter such as `"` to allow for either `,` or `;` in context without it being treated as a delimiter.

Hope this helps!