# Product SKU requirements. What characters are restricted from a product SKU and can there be spaces in the middle of the SKU?

Tags: magento-1, importexport, sku

For product SKU's can there be spaces in the middle of the SKU?

Are there any character restrictions that can not be used for a SKU ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this two answer:

- [Importing "Ø" (special character) in Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29033/importing-%C3%98-special-character-in-magento)
- [Which characters are allowed (by default) in a SKU?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68298/which-characters-are-allowed-by-default-in-a-sku)

Answer (score 0):

1. SKU Stock Keeping Unit, is a unique identification code, usually alphanumeric.
2. It allows a particular product to be tracked for inventory purposes. Typically, an SKU (pronounced with the individual letters or as SKYEW) is associated with any purchasable item in a store or catalog.
3. You can choose any format you like for SKU but usually there is some system for choosing numbers, for example, a woman’s blouse of a particular style and size might have an SKU of “3726-8,” meaning “Style 3726, size 8.”
4. SKU is unique identification code.You can not create a product a with already existed SKU its not possible.
5. You should be able upon saving the MS Excel doc to use , instead of ; without any repercussions. I believe you can also provide an escape sequence or text delimiter such as " to allow for either , or ; in context without it being treated as a delimiter.